# Const variable as type - Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, types, constants, reducers

During learning Typescript I faced problem when I used constant variable with the value of action which I use to reducer (created to prevent typo - I have read somewhere it is good practice).

```
const INPUT_CHANGE: string = "INPUT_CHANGE";
const INPUT_BLUR: string = "INPUT_BLUR";
```

I also have created type to define reducer action:

```
type InputReducerAction =
  | { type: INPUT_CHANGE; value: string; isValid: boolean }
  | { type: INPUT_BLUR };
```

And here is my reducer:

```
const inputReducer = (state: InputReducerState, action: InputReducerAction) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INPUT_CHANGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        value: action.value,
        isValid: action.isValid,
      };
    case INPUT_BLUR:
      return {
        ...state,
        touched: true,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

When I have everythink like above `INPUT_CHANGE` and `INPUT_BLUR` in `InputReducerAction` are marked as error:

> 'INPUT_CHANGE' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof INPUT_CHANGE'?ts(2749)

> 'INPUT_BLUR' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof INPUT_BLUR'?ts(2749)

Problem disappear when I use double quotes for this constants, like so

```
type InputReducerAction =
  | { type: "INPUT_CHANGE"; value: string; isValid: boolean }
  | { type: "INPUT_BLUR" };
```

But my const variables are useless right now. What I have done wrong or missed?

During writing this question I got idea to use enum:

```
enum INPUT_ACTION {
  INPUT_CHANGE = "INPUT_CHANGE",
  INPUT_BLUR = "INPUT_BLUR"
}

type InputReducerAction =
  | { type: INPUT_ACTION.INPUT_CHANGE; value: string; isValid: boolean }
  | { type: INPUT_ACTION.INPUT_BLUR };

const inputReducer = (state: InputReducerState, action: InputReducerAction) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INPUT_ACTION.INPUT_CHANGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        value: action.value,
        isValid: action.isValid,
      };
    case INPUT_ACTION.INPUT_BLUR:
      return {
        ...state,
        touched: true,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

and using it in reducer and type. Errors disappear BUT is it good idea or can I do this in a better way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [const assertions after v3.4](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to do what you are describing.

```js
const INPUT_CHANGE = "INPUT_CHANGE" as const;
const INPUT_BLUR = "INPUT_BLUR" as const;

type InputReducerAction =
  | { type: typeof INPUT_CHANGE; value: string; isValid: boolean }
  | { type: typeof INPUT_BLUR };

const changeAction: InputReducerAction = {
  type: INPUT_CHANGE, value: '', isValid: false
};

const blurAction: InputReducerAction = {
  type: INPUT_BLUR
};
```

The problem is that the JavaScript variables will only have their values assigned at runtime, and TypeScript needs to know it at compile time. Using the const assertions is a way to inform the compiler that their values should not change. And when you are getting the `typeof` the variable, to use the literal value instead of the generic `string` type that is normally assigned to the variable.

Comment: However, I generally prefer using enums. Especially in cases when I may want to enumerate the values.